# pass "pointer to pointer" to a template function

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers

I have a funtion which allocates memory to a pointer as following:

```
   void initializeImageBuffer(unsigned char **image, int w, int h)
   {
        if (*image != NULL)
            delete[] *image;
        *image = new unsigned char[w * h];
   }
```

now I want to generalize the argument type (unsigned char/int/double) using function template. Thats what I did:

```
 template<typename T, int, int>
 void initializeImageBuffer(T **image, int w, int h)
   {
        if (*image != NULL)
            delete[] *image;
        *image = new T[w * h];
   }
```

But there is an error using the function like:

```
    unsigned char* image;
    initializeImageBuffer(&image, 200, 200);
```

"There is no instance of overloading function with these argument types. The Arguments types are (unsigned char**, int, int)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<typename T, int, int>
```

Here you declare that your template has three parameters, the type `T` and two unnamed `int`s. Since there is no way to deduce the value of the `int`s at the call site, you would need to provide them explicitly, along with `T` since you can only provide template arguments from left to right:

```
initializeImageBuffer<unsigned char, 42, 42>(&image, 200, 200);
```

However, what you most probably want is just to drop these `int`s, they have absolutely no use here.

```
template<typename T>
void initializeImageBuffer(T **image, int w, int h)
```

Answer (score 5):

You might confuse template parameters with function parameters. `int, int` in template parameter list are unnecessary here, and can't be deduced from the function invoking, that's why compiler complains.

Just remove them:

```
template<typename T>
void initializeImageBuffer(T **image, int w, int h)
{
    if (*image != NULL)
        delete[] *image;
    *image = new T[w * h];
}
```